# eclipse swt ExpandBar: wrong size on expand/collaps events

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swt

I have the following layout in eclipse SWT: A GridLayout with one column and two children, one at the top, one at the bottom. The bottom one is the Expandpar. When the ExpandBar is expanded or collapsed, the size of the two children should be updated. Here is the Code:

```
package tests.julia.layout;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ExpandBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ExpandItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MyLayoutExpandBar {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        final Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell (display);
        shell.setLayout (new FillLayout());

        final Composite parent = new Composite (shell, SWT.BORDER);
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        final ExpandBar expandBar = new ExpandBar (parent, SWT.V_SCROLL);
        expandBar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, false));

        ExpandItem item = new ExpandItem (expandBar, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("Expand Item");
        item.setHeight(200);
        item.setExpanded(true);

        Group group = new Group(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
        group.setText("Item Content");
        item.setControl(group);


        /* Listener */
        expandBar.addListener(SWT.Expand, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Expand: " + expandBar.getSize());
                        parent.layout();
                        System.out.println("Expand: " + expandBar.getSize());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        expandBar.addListener(SWT.Collapse, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Collapse: " + expandBar.getSize());
                        parent.layout();
                        System.out.println("Collapse: " + expandBar.getSize());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        shell.setText("Shell");
        shell.setSize(300, 300);
        shell.open ();

        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ())
                display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }
}
```

This works correct under Windows, but under Linux the size of the ExpandBar is small when expanded and large when collapsed, so just opposite to what it should be. When the Shell is resized (by dragging its border) the size of the ExpandBar becomes correct.

Does anyone know how to make this right?

Thanks, Julia

Answer (score 0):

This thing turned out to be most probably an Ubuntu only bug.
See this bug report
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532546

Answer (score 0):

A workaround similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7633840/3907364) seems to be working for this problem.

I'm using the `ExpandBar` directly on a `Shell` with a vertical `RowLayout` on top of it and adding the following `ExpandListener` to the bar resolves the problem for me:

```
expandBar.addExpandListener(new ExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemExpanded(ExpandEvent e) {
        changed(e, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemCollapsed(ExpandEvent e) {
        changed(e, false);
    }

    private void changed(ExpandEvent e, boolean expand) {
        if (e.item instanceof ExpandItem) {
            ExpandItem expItem = (ExpandItem) e.item;
            expandBar.setLayoutData(new RowData(expandBar.getSize().x,
                    expandBar.getSize().y + (expand ? expItem.getHeight() : -expItem.getHeight())));
            shell.layout();
        }
    }
});
```